# Folder creation date is very recent, while last modified is years ago

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ntfs, roaming-profile, folder-redirection

We're experiencing some weird stuff with our roaming user profiles. We use folder redirection for Documents/Pictures/Music/Destkop/Downloads, yet these folders are being created in the roaming user profile (they shouldn't).

Looking at the dates for these folders it's quite obvious that we're hitting some kind of bug with NTFS. How else is this possible (pic)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder was copied on 18.01.2013 (1/18/13) from one that was last modified 14.07.2009 (7/14/09).

Comment: Yup - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648 for what NTFS does with time stamps on files.

Comment: I guess we should look elsewhere, since we keep getting these folders in our user profiles (even after I manually delete them).